# Community Promotion Ads - 2014

Tags: discussion, community-ads

It's the time of the year again, namely it is December 2013, and so we shall now refresh our Community Promotion Ads for the new year.

#### What are Community Promotion Ads?

Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will show up on the main site, in the right sidebar. The purpose of this question is the vetting process. Images of the advertisements are provided, and community voting will enable the advertisements to be shown.

#### Why do we have Community Promotion Ads?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- the site's twitter account
- useful tools or resources for the mathematically inclined
- interesting articles or findings for the curious
- cool events or conferences
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. This also serves as a way to promote information and resources that are *relevant to your own community's interests*, both for those already in the community and those yet to join.

#### Why do we reset the ads every year?

Some services will maintain usefulness over the years, while other things will wane to allow for new faces to show up. Resetting the ads every year helps accommodate this, and allows old ads that have served their purpose to be cycled out for fresher ads for newer things. This helps keep the material in the ads relevant to not just the subject matter of the community, but to the current status of the community. We reset the ads once a year, every December.

The community promotion ads have no restrictions against reposting an ad from a previous cycle. If a particular service or ad is very valuable to the community and will continue to be so, it is a good idea to repost it. It may be helpful to give it a new face in the process, so as to prevent the imagery of the ad from getting stale after a year of exposure.

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag. In addition to enabling the functionality of the advertisements, this tag also pre-fills the answer form with the above required form.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be **220 x 250 pixels**
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently **6**) before it will be shown on the main site.

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/1165).

Comment: Is it okay to supply double resolution ads for retina screens?  I see that some people [do this](http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/a/1884/31058) on AskDifferent, but I wasn't sure if anything special needs to be done to make it work.

Comment: Also, what about hosting it somewhere else to make the ad dynamic?  The same ad I linked to above has this as well.  [One of our ads](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1168/12) could benefit from being dynamic.

Comment: @Szabolcs Ask the Ask Different folk how they do it. We didn't have any problem when they did it so as long as you perform it the same way, that's fine. Same deal with how the updates work.

Answer (score 33):

[image: Mathematica Programming by Leonid Shifrin]

Comment: @leonid hope you don't mind this (or the color, but I like this shade today...:)

Comment: Thanks. And I do like the color. Yes, I think I like this stuff, perhaps it deserves my vote :)

Answer (score 29):

[image: Download your PDF copy of Power Programming with Mathematica now! While stocks last...]

Comment: The bar bending the wrong way is *still* driving me crazy a year later.  When I reach [full insanity](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/618728) know that this was a contributing factor. :-p

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Actually, the bar could be bending that way, it just means that whoever is holding it has an insane power, to both withstand the gravity *and* bend the bar. That was probably intentional.

Comment: @Leonid You've got it all wrong.  Those are obviously [Star Trek magnetic gravity boots](http://i.stack.imgur.com/U8AKj.jpg) and he is hanging from the ceiling.  *We* are upside-down.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Indeed, you must be right...

Comment: ...says @Leonid while backing away slowly. :o)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard lol ) I think, anyone of us would cause most "normal" people to back away slowly. I also actually think that Mathematica has a potential to make originally normal people completely nuts, if they start to "consume" it in too large quantities. I know I was very close to that at some point (assuming I didn't cross that line already:)), and I know a few people with similar feelings. And I actually heard of a few people who truly became insane after working in M too much. So, as they say, there is a piece of joke in every joke :)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Just a couple more months, then you can create a new ad...!

Answer (score 25):

[image: Try the StackExchange image uploader for Mathematica]

Answer (score 23):

[image: MATLink – Seamlessly call MATLAB from Mathematica]

Comment: Note about image size: it's double size (2x) for retina screens.

Comment: Will these ads be served to non-retina users as well?

Comment: @rm-rf I don't see why not.  They use ads like this on Apple.SE too.  I don't think that the pages served to retina or non-retina computers are different.   It just gets downscaled.

Comment: @rm-rf OK, just checked.  They show up on non-retina computers.

Comment: Thanks for checking!

Comment: @rm-rf I was lucky: this ad came up on the second refresh.

Answer (score 21):

[image: The ultimate list of Mathematica resources]

Answer (score 19):

[image: Mathematica plugin for IntelliJIDEA]

Comment: Hi,Szabolcs, Could you tell me what font the sentence `Advanced syntax highlighting` used?

Comment: @Tangshutao You need to ask halirutan as he made it.

Comment: @halirutan, Could you tell me what font the sentence `Advanced syntax highlighting` used?

Comment: @Tangshutao I will look it up in the Illustrator file next week.

Comment: @halirutan,Thanks! :-)

Comment: @Tangshutao I'm not entirely sure, since I cannot find my original Illustrator file, but I believe I used [Gill Sans](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gill_Sans) for this part.

Comment: @halirutan, I know, thanks sincerely!:-)

Answer (score 18):

[Browse through our unanswered questions! http://mma-se-ads.herokuapp.com/static/mathematica/unanswered.png](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/unanswered)

Comment: This ad will update automatically.

Comment: Can I just remove "ematica" from the .png link to get the same thing for [MSE](http://math.stackexchange.com/unanswered)...?

Comment: @draks... For some reason, I didn't get this comment and just happened to notice it now. It is not possible yet, but if you send me a template with the right dimensions that matches your site's theme then I can implement it. I have done this for [physics SE](http://mma-se-ads.herokuapp.com/static/physics/unanswered.png) before. I'll need a template like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/2X6Xn.png) (leave the unanswered count empty) and also the name of the font desired for the counter.

Comment: @rm-rf Hello, I just saw this and thought it's a great idea. Would it be too bold of me to ask if you could make one for [movies.se]? The template would be [this one](http://i.imgur.com/AS2SVx1.png) and the number would be best in some classic 42pt Arial Black with RGB (99,168,180), basically like [this example](http://i.imgur.com/kBB8Aqy.png). In the case you don't want to do it (which would be totally ok), could you provide me some hints as how to make such dynamic ads myself? Thank you.

Comment: @ChristianRau Sure, I'll look into it perhaps this week. I'm a little hesitant because Heroku (where I'm hosting my webapp) has removed the free tier and I'm not sure if restarting my dyno will bump me up to the paid tier. This is just a simple webapp that looks at where the request originated, uses the api to pull the unanswered count and then makes a composite png file. Adding an additional site is very easy with the template you've provided. I'll do one of two things: If I can stay in the free tier, I'll simply add in. If not, I'll just open source the code so that any site can set it up.

Comment: Hi @R.M., can I ask the same favour again? We need to change the canvas to [this one](http://i.stack.imgur.com/weVWD.png) to meet the new size specs. Is that a reasonable ask? Ideally Liberation Sans Bold on the counter, to look like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/OCjWb.png). Is that something you've got time for, and which is allowed by the web app tier? Or is the code lost in some previous machine? Thanks a huge bunch in advance!

Comment: As a side note, I'm puzzled to note that the author mark on this question shows your old username, rm-rf, even though the revision history has the new username.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty That is a known bug w/ Community posts. Re: updating it, I'll take a look this weekend.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty I haven't forgotten about this... I still have the code and everything and made updates to the code for the new image size. I seem to have forgotten how exactly to deploy my stuff to Heorku though :P (It's been ~2 years since I last pushed a change) I'll definitely find some time for it during this week/coming weekend. In the meantime, you can continue using the same link. It appears that the old ads are working fine w/ whitespace and the new ad will be available at the same link.

Comment: @R.M. if you get time let us know, so we can provide you image for movies.se, as last year's ChristianRau' provided image is not applicable anymore. And we didn't got it last time either ;)

Comment: btw, I still haven't forgotten about this, but SE appears to still be running our old ads, so... just buying myself more time :P

Comment: I've found at least two repos on Github with the source for this - but neither allows to open issues (like [here](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/5786/33876)). Which is the correct one?

Comment: @MartinSchröder I don't know; neither of those are mine. I wrote mine from scratch and I have not put my code on Github or anywhere public. I mentioned the reason for not updating this a few comments up in a reply to Christian Rau — My code is deployed on a Heroku dyno and they changed their pricing model. If I change it now and make a new deploy, I might have to start paying for it which is why it hasn't been updated to the wider ad format.

Answer (score 18):

[image: The biggest collection of Mathematica resources evah]

Comment: I wondered whether this might be a possibly welcome addition to the current set of Mathematica-focused community ads... ("Ceci n'est pas une framboise...")

Comment: I think there is a way for the picture to change, rather than having two separate ads... ask @rm-rf?

Comment: Hehe, is this meant to be WL on the **Raspberry** Pi? :D

Comment: @rm-rf For legal reasons, I couldn't possibly comment...:]

Comment: I wasn't sure how to reach you (you haven't been to chat recently), so I'm commenting here: 1. it turns out you can make double size (440 by 500) ads which will look very nice on high dpi screens. 2. if you like you could make an ad [for this thread](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/428/what-third-party-packages-do-you-use) in the style of your other ads.  Just an idea :-)

Comment: @OleksandrR. and cormullion: I wrote a webapp that can update the ads dynamically (see my ads on bounties and unanswered questions). I can also include your multiple ads pointing to the resources question in my webapp and provide the link to the (dynamic) image, if you'd like.

Answer (score 16):

[image: Mathematica Packages]

Comment: @szabolcs - a double-size image for retina displays. I had trouble keeping the file down to the 150KB size limit... :(

Comment: Great!  It's only 73 kB so you're well below the limit.  Let's see if it will work right away (after it gets the 6 votes).

Comment: @Szabolcs :) I had to remove all gradients, drop shadows, background textures, etc. to get this 440x500 PNG down to 150K or less. It's probably for the best. But I won't rescale the other ads (the raspberry was 400KB when blown, er, up... :)

Comment: **Note about image size:**  This size (2x) *is* actually acceptable and it's meant for high resolution (retina) screens.

Comment: @szabolcs it worked! (I had a page showing this ad...)

Answer (score 13):

[Checkout the featured questions! http://mma-se-ads.herokuapp.com/static/mathematica/bounty.png](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=featured)

Comment: This ad will update automatically with the current bounty stats. If there are no featured questions, then one of these two: http://i.stack.imgur.com/N7S9o.png and http://i.stack.imgur.com/02gYj.png will be chosen at random. Ping me either here or in chat if you have suggestions.

Answer (score 10):

[image]

Answer (score 8):

[image: Programming Puzzles and Code Golf]

Comment: This Code Golf ad is from [a promotion on our meta site.](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/1356/3808) [Here is its counterpart ad](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1281/12025).

Answer (score 8):

[image: The International Mathematica Symposium]

Comment: Should this still be up?